# Left Shift Key acts like it's held too long

Tags: 13.04, keyboard, logitech

I have an obscure problem with a Logitech K810 Bluetooth Keyboard. Everything works perfectly with the exception of the left shift key, it acts as though I have it pressed down for about two seconds longer than I really do. Right shift key works properly, but the left one runs a little slow. I checked the keyboard out and it doesn't appear to be getting physically stuck. I know it's a small problem but it can be annoying when you type at 120wpm! Perhaps it is simply a glitch that can be solved by mapping the key to appear as the right shift key? I have no idea which is why I'm posing the question to you guys. Anyone else has a similar issue?

Running Ubuntu 13.04 desktop 64-bit

Comment: Turns out this is just how the keyboard works.  Tried it with the PS3, same thing.  Would try it with Windows, but yuck, not going to install Windows to test a theory.

Comment: I have a Logitech K810 and the left shift key does not act abnormally. You should consider returning the keyboard for replacement.